# Trying to optimize code that creates a running tally of a team's seasonal stats and adds it to their boxscore

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to compile stats for college basketball games. I have two inputs:

`regular_season_boxscore_df`: A DataFrame consiststing of regular season boxscores.
It looks like this:

```
print(regular_season_boxscore_df.head())
   Season  DayNum  WTeamID  WScore  LTeamID  ...  LAst LTO  LStl  LBlk  LPF
0    2003      10     1104      68     1328  ...     8  18     9     2   20
1    2003      10     1272      70     1393  ...     7  12     8     6   16
2    2003      11     1266      73     1437  ...     9  12     2     5   23
3    2003      11     1296      56     1457  ...     9  19     4     3   23
4    2003      11     1400      77     1208  ...    12  10     7     1   14

[5 rows x 34 columns]

print(regular_season_boxscore_df.columns)
Index(['Season', 'DayNum', 'WTeamID', 'WScore', 'LTeamID', 'LScore', 'WLoc',
       'NumOT', 'WFGM', 'WFGA', 'WFGM3', 'WFGA3', 'WFTM', 'WFTA', 'WOR', 'WDR',
       'WAst', 'WTO', 'WStl', 'WBlk', 'WPF', 'LFGM', 'LFGA', 'LFGM3', 'LFGA3',
       'LFTM', 'LFTA', 'LOR', 'LDR', 'LAst', 'LTO', 'LStl', 'LBlk', 'LPF'],
      dtype='object')
```

`running_team_stats_df`: A DataFrame which will contain the running totals for a team's stats for each season. It's filled with zeros and looks like this:

```
print(running_team_stats_df.head())
  season team_id day_num FGA FGM  Ast  Blk  ...  FTA  FTM  NumOT   OR   PF  Stl   TO
0   2003    1101       0   0   0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1   2003    1102       0   0   0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2   2003    1103       0   0   0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3   2003    1104       0   0   0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4   2003    1105       0   0   0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

[5 rows x 17 columns]
print(running_team_stats_df.columns)
Index(['season', 'team_id', 'day_num', 'FGA', 'FGM', 'Ast', 'Blk', 'DR',
       'FGA3', 'FGM3', 'FTA', 'FTM', 'NumOT', 'OR', 'PF', 'Stl', 'TO'],
      dtype='object')
```

(I realize there's a 'Season' vs 'season' and a 'DayNum' vs 'day_num' naming scheme discrepancy. That's one of the first things I want to fix)

On to my code. I want to expand the regular season box score to include a running list of stats for the current season. Currently, the boxscore only lists that games stats for the winning team and losing team. I want to have those teams season stats in there as well. Here's the code I'm using to get that done:

```
def expand_regular_season(regular_season_boxscore_df, running_team_stats_df):
    print('Expanding regular season to add detail...', end='')

    # Create expanded boxscore df
    regular_season_detail_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = [
        'Season', 'DayNum', 'WTeamID', 'WScore', 'LTeamID', 'LScore', 'WLoc', 'NumOT', 
        'WFGM', 'WFGA', 'WFGM3', 'WFGA3', 'WFTM', 'WFTA', 'WOR', 'WDR',
        'WAst', 'WTO', 'WStl', 'WBlk', 'WPF', 

        'year_WNumOT', 'year_WFGM', 'year_WFGA', 'year_WFGM3', 'year_WFGA3',
        'year_WFTM', 'year_WFTA', 'year_WOR', 
        'year_WDR', 'year_WAst', 'year_WTO', 'year_WStl', 'year_WBlk', 'year_WPF',

        'LFGM', 'LFGA', 'LFGM3', 'LFGA3',
        'LFTM', 'LFTA', 'LOR', 'LDR', 'LAst', 'LTO', 'LStl', 'LBlk', 'LPF',

        'year_LNumOT', 'year_LFGM', 'year_LFGA', 'year_LFGM3', 'year_LFGA3',
        'year_LFTM', 'year_LFTA', 'year_LOR', 
        'year_LDR', 'year_LAst', 'year_LTO', 'year_LStl', 'year_LBlk', 'year_LPF'])



    with tqdm(total=len(regular_season_boxscore_df)) as pbar:
        for _, row in regular_season_boxscore_df.iterrows():

            # Create a condition for easier locating based on the season and the team
            win_team_cond  = ((running_team_stats_df.season == row.Season) &(running_team_stats_df.team_id == row.WTeamID))
            lose_team_cond = ((running_team_stats_df.season == row.Season) & (running_team_stats_df.team_id == row.LTeamID))


        # Create a series that pulls the running teams stats prior to the current game
        _ds = pd.Series({
            'year_WNumOT': running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'NumOT'].values[0], 
            'year_WFGM'  : running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'FGM'].values[0], 
            'year_WFGA'  : running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'FGA'].values[0], 
            'year_WFGM3' : running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'FGM3'].values[0], 
            'year_WFGA3' : running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'FGA'].values[0], 
            'year_WFTM'  : running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'FTM'].values[0], 
            'year_WFTA'  : running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'FTA'].values[0], 
            'year_WOR'   : running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'OR'].values[0], 
            'year_WDR'   : running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'DR'].values[0], 
            'year_WAst'  : running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'Ast'].values[0], 
            'year_WTO'   : running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'TO'].values[0], 
            'year_WStl'  : running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'Stl'].values[0], 
            'year_WBlk'  : running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'Blk'].values[0], 
            'year_WPF'   : running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'PF'].values[0],

            'year_LNumOT': running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'NumOT'].values[0], 
            'year_LFGM'  : running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'FGM'].values[0], 
            'year_LFGA'  : running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'FGA'].values[0], 
            'year_LFGM3' : running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'FGM3'].values[0], 
            'year_LFGA3' : running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'FGA'].values[0], 
            'year_LFTM'  : running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'FTM'].values[0], 
            'year_LFTA'  : running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'FTA'].values[0], 
            'year_LOR'   : running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'OR'].values[0], 
            'year_LDR'   : running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'DR'].values[0], 
            'year_LAst'  : running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'Ast'].values[0], 
            'year_LTO'   : running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'TO'].values[0], 
            'year_LStl'  : running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'Stl'].values[0], 
            'year_LBlk'  : running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'Blk'].values[0], 
            'year_LPF'   : running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'PF'].values[0]})

        # Create a new row that contains the original box score and the current running stats for the season
        regular_season_detail_df = regular_season_detail_df.append(row.append(_ds), ignore_index = True)


        # Update the running stats
        running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'day_num'] = row['DayNum']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'FGA'] += row['WFGA']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'FGM'] += row['WFGM']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'Ast'] += row['WAst']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'Blk'] += row['WBlk']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'DR'] += row['WDR']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'FGA3'] += row['WFGA3']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'FGM3'] += row['WFGM3']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'FTA'] += row['WFTA']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'FTM'] += row['WFTM']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'NumOT'] += row['NumOT']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'OR'] += row['WOR']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'PF'] += row['WPF']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'Stl'] += row['WStl']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[win_team_cond, 'TO'] += row['WTO']


        running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'day_num'] = row['DayNum']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'FGA'] += row['LFGA']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'FGM'] += row['LFGM']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'Ast'] += row['LAst']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'Blk'] += row['LBlk']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'DR'] += row['LDR']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'FGA3'] += row['LFGA3']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'FGM3'] += row['LFGM3']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'FTA'] += row['LFTA']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'FTM'] += row['LFTM']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'NumOT'] += row['NumOT']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'OR'] += row['LOR']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'PF'] += row['LPF']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'Stl'] += row['LStl']
        running_team_stats_df.loc[lose_team_cond, 'TO'] += row['LTO']

        pbar.update()

    print('done')
    return regular_season_detail_df
```

I'm very new to Pandas and I'm sure there's a better way to be using it that doesn't involve iterating through every row. There's 87504 boxscores to get through and it took about four and a half hours to run, so not ideal.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! – While you question is good, you should change the title of this post to a general description of what the code does. Asking for a better way to something is implied in any code review posts, and is therefore unnecessary. Check out this (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for more information.

Comment: When you say the `running_team_stats_df` is a running total, does this mean that for each team it contains their stats for each day of the season? Are all of your stats additive? Can you share a larger sample of your data, covering each of the changing things (team ID, day_num, etc), for this a link would suffice?

Comment: running_team_stats_df contains the current seasonal stats for that team and season. So for example, there will be one unique row for each team for each season (2003 to current). I call it a running total because when I'm iterating through the season, it will be 'up to date' at that time and that way I can add that data to the regular season box score. So the box score wont only have that games stats, it'll have that teams seasons stats as well.